# convert xls to xlsm using excelcnv.exe

Tags: c#, sharepoint, excel, console-application

I created a console application using the Microsoft Office utilities: `ppcnvcom.exe`, `excelcnv.exe`, `wordconv.exe` to convert `doc` to `docx`, `xls` to `xlsx` and `ppt` to `pptx` respectively.

Does anyone know how to convert `xls` to `xlsm`?

`OFC.exe` is one option, but when I called it from sharepoint it was not successfully converted. The converter is blocked due to some security issue. `OFC.exe` automatically detects if there is a macro in the `xls` macro and then converts it to the `xlsm` file.

Is there a way to do this using `excelcnv.exe`?

Comment: Is there much difference between an xslx and an xslm in terms of the data? I'd always assumed it was just the extension change, and maybe one or two properties in one of the XML files

Comment: if you edit the excel file xls with xlsm extention then your file cant be open. in xlsm file we added some macro for ex: copy word to word. means if you create macro who will copy word. then you need to just enable  the macro for excel file and go to view > macro > View Macros> then click on run. then your macro will run and copy the word.

Comment: Can you please give more detail - Where are these files stored? Why are you using these converter programs? What is the text of the security error?

Comment: i have use document converter object model in sharepoint 2010 to convert the file. for this i have created one console application and use ofc.exe file(is a microsoft exe which convert the 2003 file to 2007 file format) to convert the file. but if i run the ofc.exe alone then it works fine. but in sharepoint it not give me correct output. if you want more detail for Document Converter in sharepoint 2010 please google in internet.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, you can't do this with excelcnv.exe as it requires a file name. It would be wonky to name all your .xls files as .xlsm and then go through 1 by 1 to figure out which ones don't have macros.

Based on your comments, you've tried using OFC.exe, which is a much better way of going about this for what you're looking for. We should focus efforts on that instead. What exactly is the error you are receiving and how are you configuring your .INI file? (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/19/bulk-convert-doc-to-docx.aspx for an example).

You have to use the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class to run OFC.exe and then pass in the right [command line arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx) to point to your INI file.

---

**EDIT: 2011-03-11**:
I guess if no more details are forthcoming to help troubleshoot this, I'll stick by the answer in the first paragraph as answering the OP's question: *...you can't do this with excelcnv.exe as it requires a file name.*

Comment: i had already use process class and pass the correct argument. when i ran the console application individually then it convert correctly. but when i call from share point environment it give me error like: failed to convert the file. i have use sharepoint 2010 document convert object model.

Comment: @Suresh Chaudhary: what is the error you receive back from the document conversion OM? does it have an error number?

Comment: no i am not get any error number. error like this: error: xyz.doc failed to convert the file.

Comment: @Suresh Chaudhary: Ah, looks like if you're using Process, you should be using the Document Converter's Run Command instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms559247.aspx. Barring this not fixing your issue, please provide MUCH more detail about each step you're taking (including if you are using C# or VB.NET).

Comment: i have implemented the code in c#. there is not issue in run command . i am talking about ofc.exe file. its not work in sharepoint environment. i suggest just created test web part and run the ofc.exe using process class. its give error: failed to convert the file. i had face same issue.

Comment: This is not likely a failure of OFC.exe, it's a combination of your INI file and how you are calling the run command in SharePoint. There is almost nothing that can be done to help you with the little information supplied. Like I said before, you'll need to supply much more info like your INI file and your code.

Comment: but when i ran the OFC.EXE file using console application then it works perfectly. but when i ran from sharepoint environment it give me error: failed to convert the file. The sharepoint 2010 object model is: when we use document converter using sharepoint 2010 object model, it run from the document launcher service. first we can setup the service using central administratoration. then i have copy my console application exe in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\TransformApps this folder. this is the folder which contain the exe file.

Comment: now, i have created one feature like:  <DocumentConverter
     Id="BDACF29C-C1A0-4A35-8713-BD8E25BE145E"
     Name="SE Doc to Docx Converter"
     App="SEDocumentConverter.exe"
     From="doc"
     To="docx"
    /> .  i have assign exe file which location is :C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\TransformApps. now, when launcher service run it called the exe file. this will create the problem. it gives me error: failed to convert the file. but when i individually run the console application it run without error.

Answer (score 1):

You could try: http://sourceforge.net/projects/b2xtranslator/ instead