# Ignore the "Select Sheet" message on Excel Interop

Tags: excel-interop

Maybe someone here can help me out with this. I am trying to convert all XLS to XLSX/M files with powershell and interop. So far so good. In my next step, I have to adapt the link sources in each file, which works sometimes (also from XLS to XLSX/M).
I don’t know why, but sometimes the original worksheet name does not exist in the linked Excel file and results in a pop up with which the user has to interact:

[image: Select Sheet]

I actually really don’t care so much about the sheet and I just want to ignore the message so that the script can continue.
In my code I use the function ChangeLink, like this:

```
$workbook.ChangeLink($fileLink_old, $fileLink_new)
```

I also have deactivated any warning on the excel object itself, but nothing helps:

```
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$excel.WarnOnFunctionNameConflict = $False
$excel.AskToUpdateLinks = $False
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
```

The most convinient way for me would be just ignoring the pop up.
Is there a way without going through all cells by itself or modifing the externalLinks/_rels  inside of the excel file?

Thanks in advance

Stephan

Edit:
To loop through each cell, not really efficient

```
ForEach ($Worksheet in @($workbook.Sheets)) {
Write-Host $Worksheet.Name
    ForEach ($filelink in $fileLinks){
        $worksheetname = $null
        $fl_we = $fileLink.Substring(0, $fileLink.LastIndexOf('.'))
        $found = $Worksheet.Cells.Find($fl_we.Substring(0, $fl_we.LastIndexOf('\')) + '\[' + $fl_we.Substring($fl_we.LastIndexOf('\')+1))
        if($found -ne $null){
            Write-Host Search $filelink
            Write-Host $Worksheet.Cells($found.Row,$found.Column).Formula
            $str_formula = $Worksheet.Cells($found.Row,$found.Column).Formula
            $worksheetname = $str_formula.Substring($str_formula.IndexOf(']')+1,$str_formula.IndexOf('!')-$str_formula.IndexOf(']')-2)
            Write-Host $worksheetname -ForegroundColor DarkGray
            #Add worksheets with filename to list
        }

    }
}

#Check if worksheet exists in linked file
```

Comment: the MS office excelcnv might be worth a try `pathToEXCEL.EXE\excelcnv.exe -oice "old.xls" "new.xlsm"` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192511/convert-xls-to-xlsm-using-excelcnv-exe/5240095

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as far as I can see the excelcnv.exe is just for converting xls to xlsx? My problem is a link inside of the xlsx file which points still to an old, not existing xls file. I need to change just the shortcut name from xls to xlsx. But thereby the problem is that a worksheet does not exist and I cannot just ignore the warning.

Comment: I misunderstood it as conversion without opening the file in Excel. Maybe you can use OpenXML/ClosedXML or similar library to change the links after the conversions.

Comment: I guess I ll just forget about it. Yesterday I tried to figure out the linked worksheet names but I would have to loop through all the document: